# Calculation Transitivity of a Graph from the Adj Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, graph-theory, adjacency-matrix

I'm trying to calculate the transitivity of a graph, also known as it's global clustering coefficient. The formula for this is: # of triangles / # of connected triples as seen [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clustering_coefficient). While I can easily calculate the number of triangles in a graph by taking $tr(A^3)/6$ where $A$ is the adjacency matrix, I have had less success calculating the denominator. Since $A^3$ has entry $a_{i,j}$ giving the number of paths from $i$ to $j$, I had thought that I could get the total number of paths of length $3$ by simply summing any row of $A^3$ and dividing by $3$, but this doesn't give the right answer according to the code I have written.

This is for a program, so if there isn't a formula then pseudocode for the calculation would work too.

Comment: ``Since $A^3$ has entry $a_{i, j}$ giving the number of paths from $i$ to $j$''

You don't say anything about length of such path. It is not good.

Comment: Connected triples are a path of length 2

Comment: You should sum the rows of $A^2$ then...

Comment: I mean you should fix any $A^3$ to $A^2$ except the one inside the trace.

Comment: @StellaBiderman What about the elements of the diagonal? you shouldn't include them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\sum_{i\neq j}(A^2)_{i,j}\over2$ should work.

Answer (score 0):

Given the adjacency matrix $A$ (zeros in diagonal) of an undirected graph,

the number of triangles is
$$
\frac{trace(A^3)}{6}
$$

the number of connected triples is
$$
\frac{  \sum_{ij} (A^2)_{ij} -  trace(A^2)}{2}
$$

For example, given this graph and its adjacency matrix
[image]
the first formula will give value 2.

For this graph 
[image]
the second formula will give value 5.